# NuGet restore .vcxitems error when C++ Universal App is in solution

Tags: msbuild, nuget, win-universal-app, c++-cx, nuget-package-restore

I have opened [issue](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4401) on NuGet site.

The problem seems to be with C++ Universal App library in solution in which I try to run `nuget restore` command. I get the following error:

`The project file "SparkiyEngine.Language.Lua\SparkiyEngine.Language.Lua.Shared\SparkiyEngine.Language.Lua.Shared.vcxitems" is in the ".vcproj" file format, which MSBuild no longer supports. Please convert the project by opening it in the Visual Studio IDE or running the conversion tool, or use MSBuild 3.5 or earlier to build it.`

The project that is mentioned in error message is `Shared` project of WinRT C++ Lib.

Is there something I can add to the command that would bypass this project or ignore it?

Useful links:
[Project](https://github.com/Sparkiy/sparkiy-client), 
[CI](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/AleksandarDev/sparkiy-client/build/0.1.40)

Comment: OK, found the issue and fixed it. Will deploy update today.

AppVeyor had similar problem, here's how they solved it today: "The problem was in AppVeyor runner using old 4.0 build framework libraries for analyzing solution files. Switching to 12.0 fixes the issue. Guess the same could be done in nuget.exe too." http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/1239-how-to-get-more-logs-for-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-errors#comment_35592708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place following config file next to `nuget.exe`

`nuget.exe.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Engine" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I just don't understand those that downvote and don't explain why they downvoted the answer or question. This solved my problem. Look at my last comment on question. I didn't solve this problem myself so I can't explain in detail what is going on. So please don't be rude.